# How to give AbstractUser permissions to a users' group?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have user model inherited from `AbstractUser` called `CustomAbstractUser`. When I try to assign the permissions of this model to a user group, nothing is done. No trace of the assignment in the database. When I go through the administration interface, it works without problem. But programmatically not.

```py
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(CustomAbstractUser)
add_user = Permission.objects.get(
        codename="add_customabstractuser", content_type=content_type
    )
change_user = Permission.objects.get(
        codename="change_customabstractuser", content_type=content_type
    )
...
admin, _ = Group.objects.get_or_create(name="AdminUser")
...
admin.permissions.set([add_user, change_user, view_user])
```

By following this procedure with other models, it works without any problem. Also note that `CustomAbstractUser` is in a different application than the other models.

Comment: Abstract user, or admin user?

Comment: `CustomAbstractUser` inherited from django `AbstractUser` model. `admin` is a group. All users in `admin` group have `is_superuser` and `is_staff` to `False`.